# Emacs Evil smooth-scroll and next match jumps

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I installed `smooth-scroll` which works nice with `isearch` jumps, but it doesn't work with jumps in Evil (the `n` and `Shift-n`). How can I make the `n` and `Shift-n` jumps in Emacs Evil to be smooth?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this doesn't respond to my question but I found that `subimity-scroll` does the job.